# django migrate error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of relation gallery_image

Tags: python, django

I've done some changes to a site on the local version, pushed models to the server and did a makemigrations

```
(revampenv) sammy@samuel-pc:~/revamp$ python manage.py makemigrations gallery
Migrations for 'gallery':
  0032_auto_20170829_0058.py:
    - Create model Area
    - Create model Color
    - Create model ThumbnailCache
    - Add field unique_key_string to image
    - Alter field example on image
    - Alter field timeline on image
```

worked fine then I tried to migrate and I get this error

```
(revampenv) sammy@samuel-pc:~/revamp$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, sessions, admin, auth, thumbnail, contenttypes, gallery
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying gallery.0032_auto_20170829_0058...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 21, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 396, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of relation gallery_image
```

I've had this or a similar error before when the database db had a duplicate below for the local env but that's not the case now.

(note) this also fails for other models

```
(revampenv) sammy@samuel-pc:~/revamp$ python manage.py makemigrations account
Migrations for 'account':
  0003_userprofile_bio.py:
    - Add field bio to userprofile


(revampenv) sammy@samuel-pc:~/revamp$ python manage.py migrate
  ...
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of relation account_userprofile
```

**Update**
tried to edit database owner

```
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE color_db OWNER TO revamp;
ALTER DATABASE

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'color_db',
        'USER': 'revamp',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

but it still returns the same error

```
(revampenv) sammy@samuel-pc:~/revamp$ python manage.py migrate
...
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of relation account_userprofile
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set current user as database owner. For this you need to open postgres shell and execute query:

```
ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner
```

see details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html).

Comment: updated the question with the result for your answer, changes take effect but the error persists.